# Why do a blank Ember Object this have a retained size of ~500

Tags: javascript, memory, ember.js, google-chrome-devtools

I tried creating an Ember object using

```
c = Em.Object.create();
```

and checked the memory dump to see this

[image]

It suggests a shallow memory of 24 and retained memory of 524. My Question is, is this something to worry in terms of memory if I am keeping around 500 such Ember Objects in a Controller.

So let us say I have a controller with 500 Ember Objects in the array `content`, then the momory dump looks like this:

[image]

Here each item in array has 524 retained size, and the controller has a large retained size of 268088 as a result. Is this really a problem?

I doubt if all the Ember objects are referring to the same 524bytes of some common object referred by each one of them.

Comment: When the developers of emberjs made a good job then all objects share the same methods (made through the prototype-attribute), so at least there are only the object-methods for all objects not for each of them. Defining methods with the prototype-attribute is always recommended in terms of memory consumption. Nevertheless each object has got it's own values like for example name or id that consumes memory too for each object.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ok I finally took a good look at Ember source and figured it out. It is because [they are using `delete`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/ca04bee6c8c43140d5cad2307ce6fbafeb5d9488/packages/ember-runtime/lib/system/core_object.js#L123).

*(Ember [has fixed this now](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/2cc3d91f973a48c83bc164eb4b6f4803c040ab41#packages/ember-runtime/lib/system/core_object.js) and there should be no such drastic memory use by the blank ember objects anymore.*)

`delete` tells V8 that "I will be using this object like a hash map rather than real object" and therefore switches to an internal hash map structure to store one's properties in rather than "C struct" like construct that is a core feature in the foundation modern javascript performance is built on.

When you look at the grey `properties`, it means the space taken by the internal storage which is a hash table and therefore takes a lot of space.

I have created a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JSbMJ/

You should run a heap snapshot and look for the objects and see how hugely their sizes differ (472 vs 80):

[image]

[image]

It is absolutely not a problem though because you are only supposed to do CRUD with ember, not games, physics simulations or such.

Btw, I don't know if other engines have such a reaction on `delete` but I figure they would because such an operation doesn't make sense when you semantically have an object and is impossible in many languages.

Comment: Thank you for your response, you said I am only supposed to do CURD with Ember. But if I have a collection of 1000 objects stored in webSQL I prefer to keep them in a Controller so that I dont have to make dbrequests everytime for retrieval. Also I am doing this in ios using cordova which makes me think in terms of performance. Do you have any other suggession for this scenario? Also how does your answer relate to the other answer suggesting they are size of references collected during GC?

Comment: @sabithpocker 1000 for lifetime of the application is not that much even if they take 0.5kb each. This stuff does matter though when you create something like e.g. 60000 objects every second (a particle explosion effect in a game for instance, the more objects, the cooler it will look :P). Yes, if a blank ember object gets GCd, you get back 524 bytes.

Comment: That's some extremely interesting behaviour.  Do you have any references for this, or is this just undocumented (or sparsely so) characteristics in the V8 source code?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy [V8 is mostly undocumented](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6237120). It is tough to refer to a single line in source for this, but basically if you follow through the [DeleteProperty function here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/325d5384e9caf5281866f560fcc76abf8e2ed180/src/objects.cc#L5187), you will notice it will end up calling [`NormalizeProperties`](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/325d5384e9caf5281866f560fcc76abf8e2ed180/src/objects.cc#L4517) on the object - which means turning optimized properties into a hash table format (or not doing anything if they were so already).

Comment: That is very informative, thank you so much for the research. So i got the answer as each object is using up that amount.

Comment: @sabithpocker yes ember has already even fixed it... should have made an issue of it since they seem to care about it

Comment: @Esailija Thank you for the research and support. I didnt even know what the gray `properties` actually meant. Your answer was very informative.

Answer (score 2):

The retained size is the memory that will be released at the moment when GC collects the object.

In your case Ember object itself uses 24 bytes but also owns other objects in memory and the total size of these objects is 524. When you remove all the references to a particular Ember object then it becomes a garbage and it with all dependent objects that it owns exclusively will be collected at the next GC.

If you controller the only owner of the 500 Ember objects then the retained size of these objects will be added to the retained size of the controller.

[There is a good video about memory on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9Jlu_h_Lyw).